# Dynamic addition & removal in tables

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am learning Javascript and am trying to create a run-time search option from a list of data in a table. The data in the table is loaded on runtime and onKeyup I want to show only the rows which matches my condition. Below is a snippet of my code. My problem is during display, all the data gets displayed in the first column. How can I make sure that its displayed correctly.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .child {
            border: 1px solid #ff0000;
        }

        table,tr,td{
            border: 1px solid #ff0000;
        }
        </style>
        <script>
            var counter =1;
            var objList =[];
            objList[0]={name:"Nabila", jobId:"123456"};
            objList[1]={name:"Partha", jobId:"234567"};
            objList[2]={name:"Saurabh", jobId:"345678"};
            objList[3]={name:"Nabeela", jobId:"456789"};

            function loadData() {
                var objTo = document.getElementById("resultantTable");
                for(var i = 0; i < objList.length; i++){
                    var divtest = document.createElement("tr"); 
                    divtest.setAttribute("id", counter);
                    divtest.innerHTML = '<td> ' + counter + ' </td><td>' +
                        objList[i].name + '</td><td>' + objList[i].jobId + '</td>';
                    objTo.appendChild(divtest);
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            function search(){
                var edValue = document.getElementById("itemToSearch");
                var text = edValue.value;
                for(var i=0;i<objList.length;i++){
                    if((objList[i].name.toUpperCase()).indexOf(text.toUpperCase()) == -1)
                        document.getElementById(i+1).style.display ='none';
                    else
                        document.getElementById(i+1).style.display ='block';
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body onLoad="loadData();">
        <div id="list">
            <label> Text </label>
            <input type="text" id="itemToSearch" onKeyup="search(this);"/>
            <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addToList();" />
        </div>

        <div id="add">
            <div class="divAdd" >
                <table id="resultantTable" >
                    <tr>
                        <td> SL # </td>
                        <td> Name </td>
                        <td> Job id # </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>      

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the following statement:

```
document.getElementById(i+1).style.display ='block';
```

to

```
document.getElementById(i+1).style.display="table-row";
```

Comment: Thanks a ton buddy, please help me understand what does table-row mean.

Comment: You may click the following link for detail:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp